# How to query cloudwatch logs using boto3 in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda function that writes metrics to Cloudwatch. While, it writes metrics, It generates some logs in a log-group.

```
INFO:: username: simran+test@example.com ClinicID: 7667 nodename: MacBook-Pro-2.local

INFO:: username: simran+test2@example.com ClinicID: 7667 nodename: MacBook-Pro-2.local

INFO:: username: simran+test@example.com ClinicID: 7668 nodename: MacBook-Pro-2.local

INFO:: username: simran+test3@example.com ClinicID: 7667 nodename: MacBook-Pro-2.local
```

I would like to query AWS logs in past `x` hours where x could be anywhere between 12 to 24 hours, based on any of the params.

For ex:

1. Query Cloudwatch logs in last 5 hours where `ClinicID=7667`

or

2. Query Cloudwatch logs in last 5 hours where `ClinicID=7667` and `username='simran+test@example.com'`

or

3. Query Cloudwatch logs in last 5 hours where `username='simran+test@example.com'`

I am using `boto3` in Python.

Comment: just the thing I am looking for! you save me hours! thanks :)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can get what you want using CloudWatch Logs Insights.

You would use `start_query` and `get_query_results` APIs: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html

To start a query you would use (for use case 2 from your question, 1 and 3 are similar):

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

client = boto3.client('logs')

query = "fields @timestamp, @message | parse @message \"username: * ClinicID: * nodename: *\" as username, ClinicID, nodename | filter ClinicID = 7667 and username='simran+test@example.com'"

log_group = '/aws/lambda/NAME_OF_YOUR_LAMBDA_FUNCTION'

start_query_response = client.start_query(
    logGroupName=log_group,
    startTime=int((datetime.today() - timedelta(hours=5)).timestamp()),
    endTime=int(datetime.now().timestamp()),
    queryString=query,
)

query_id = start_query_response['queryId']

response = None

while response == None or response['status'] == 'Running':
    print('Waiting for query to complete ...')
    time.sleep(1)
    response = client.get_query_results(
        queryId=query_id
    )
```

Response will contain your data in this format (plus some metadata):

```
{
  'results': [
    [
      {
        'field': '@timestamp',
        'value': '2019-12-09 17:07:24.428'
      },
      {
        'field': '@message',
        'value': 'username: simran+test@example.com ClinicID: 7667 nodename: MacBook-Pro-2.local\n'
      },
      {
        'field': 'username',
        'value': 'simran+test@example.com'
      },
      {
        'field': 'ClinicID',
        'value': '7667'
      },
      {
        'field': 'nodename',
        'value': 'MacBook-Pro-2.local\n'
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you look at a related question here, please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59314132/query-cloudwatch-logs-for-distinct-values-using-boto3-in-python    @Unkindness of Datapoints

Comment: You should pay attention at the `limit` argument for `start_query` function ([link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.start_query)), which is 1000 by default. If you work with a high-density log, some events can be omitted w/o specifying higher limit.

Comment: querying using log insights is chargeable. Be cautions of the time frame and hence the amount of data the query will analyze. Run the same query in GUI to see the amount of data it processes

Comment: Note that `response['status']` can also be `Scheduled` in addition to `Running` so consider adding `or response['status'] == 'Scheduled'` to the `while` conditions.  The full list is `Scheduled`, `Running`, `Complete`, `Failed`, `Cancelled`, `Timeout` and `Unknown` from the linked docs.

Comment: Insights seem slower than querying the dumb logs in AWS CW console. The answer above seems good enough if a latency of 3-4 minutes (which is what I observe with Insights) is ok.

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve this with the [cloudWatchlogs client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.get_log_events) and a little bit of coding. You can also customize the conditions or use JSON module for a precise result.

EDIT

You can use [describe_log_streams](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.describe_log_streams) to get the streams. If you want only the latest, just put limit 1, or if you want more than one, use for loop to iterate all streams while filtering as mentioned below.

```py
    import boto3

    client = boto3.client('logs')

    ## For the latest
    stream_response = client.describe_log_streams(
        logGroupName="/aws/lambda/lambdaFnName", # Can be dynamic
        orderBy='LastEventTime',                 # For the latest events
        limit=1                                  # the last latest event, if you just want one
        )

    latestlogStreamName = stream_response["logStreams"]["logStreamName"]

    response = client.get_log_events(
        logGroupName="/aws/lambda/lambdaFnName",
        logStreamName=latestlogStreamName,
        startTime=12345678,
        endTime=12345678,
    )

    for event in response["events"]:
        if event["message"]["ClinicID"] == "7667":
            print(event["message"])
        elif event["message"]["username"] == "simran+test@example.com":
            print(event["message"])
        #.
        #.
        # more if or else conditions

    ## For more than one Streams, e.g. latest 5
    stream_response = client.describe_log_streams(
        logGroupName="/aws/lambda/lambdaFnName", # Can be dynamic
        orderBy='LastEventTime',                 # For the latest events
        limit=5
        )

    for log_stream in stream_response["logStreams"]:
        latestlogStreamName = log_stream["logStreamName"]

        response = client.get_log_events(
             logGroupName="/aws/lambda/lambdaFnName",
             logStreamName=latestlogStreamName,
             startTime=12345678,
             endTime=12345678,
        )
        ## For example, you want to search "ClinicID=7667", can be dynamic

        for event in response["events"]:
           if event["message"]["ClinicID"] == "7667":
             print(event["message"])
           elif event["message"]["username"] == "simran+test@example.com":
             print(event["message"])
           #.
           #.
           # more if or else conditions
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Log stream names are generated automatically by the lambda function so I do not know them in advance. How should I go about it?

Comment: @SannyPatel, My aws logs are as below, how can i capture the entire JSON.   
INFO  2020-11-27 10:30:09,510 [[reltiodatagateway-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT].callDnB-Main-Flow.stage1.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 80916b10-309b-11eb-ab19-0242ac110002 JSON Output After calling DnB API. Response Details {
  "jobId": 5754492016394240,
  "success": "OK",
  "message": "Scheduled"
}

Comment: Create your Lambda and define a `FunctionName` explicitly. This will allow you to create the Log Group dynamically. Another (worse) option is to query CloudFormation for the Lambda name and then build the log group name based on that. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-functionname

Comment: `orderBy='LastEventTime'`  by itself doesn't do anything. You also need to specify `descending` eg `descending=True` to get the latest event.

Answer (score 3):

I used `awslogs`. if you install it, you can do. `--watch` will tail the new logs.

```
awslogs get /aws/lambda/log-group-1 --start="5h ago" --watch
```

You can install it using

```
pip install awslogs
```

to filter you can do:

```
awslogs get /aws/lambda/log-group-1  --filter-pattern '"ClinicID=7667"' --start "5h ago" --timestamp
```

It supports multiple filter patterns as well.

```
awslogs get /aws/lambda/log-group-1  --filter-pattern '"ClinicID=7667"' --filter-pattern '" username=simran+test@abc.com"' --start "5h ago" --timestamp
```

References:

[awslogs](https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs)

[awslogs . PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/awslogs/)

Comment: are you expecting any other specific features

Comment: there are many tools like `awslogs` they pretty much do the same.

Comment: I just need to do it in Python boto3. :) @Arun K

Comment: i had some success importing awslogs from python code

Comment: It is considered good form to link to more info about any non-standard tool you recommend: https://pypi.org/project/awslogs/ or  https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs

Comment: I agree. done. thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use awswrangler:

```
import awswrangler as wr

# must define this for wrangler to work
boto3.setup_default_session(region_name=region)

df = wr.cloudwatch.read_logs(
    log_group_names=["loggroup"],
    start_time=from_timestamp,
    end_time=to_timestamp,
    query="fields @timestamp, @message | sort @timestamp desc | limit 5",
)
```

You can pass a list of the log groups needed, start and end time.
The output is a pandas DataFrame containing the results.

FYI, under the hood, awswrangler uses the boto3 commands as in @dejan answer

Answer (score 0):

I prefer client.filter_log_events from boto3.

```
# your function to parse the event.
def parse_event(event):
    pass

# my solution:
def grab_data(aws_region,
              aws_access_key_id,
              aws_secret_access_key,
              log_group_name,
              list_log_stream,
              start_time,
              end_time,
              filter_pattern):
    """
    Fetch log events from AWS CloudWatch Logs.

    Args
    ----
        aws_region (str): AWS region.
        aws_access_key_id (str): AWS access key ID.
        aws_secret_access_key (str): AWS secret access key.
        log_group_name (str): Name of the log group.
        list_log_stream (list): List of log stream names.
        start_time (int): Start time for log event retrieval in milliseconds.
        end_time (int): End time for log event retrieval in milliseconds.
        filter_pattern (str): Pattern to filter log events.

    Returns
    -------
        list: List of strings representing parsed log events.
    """
    client = boto3.client(
        service_name='logs',
        region_name=aws_region,
        aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
        aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key
    )

    rows = []
    next_token = {}
    while True:
        response = client.filter_log_events(
            logGroupName=log_group_name,
            logStreamNames=list_log_stream,
            startTime=start_time,
            endTime=end_time,
            filterPattern=filter_pattern,
            **next_token
        )

        rows += [item for item in
                 [str(parse_event(event)) for event in response['events']]
                 if item != 'None']

        if 'nextToken' not in response:
            break
        next_token = {'nextToken': response['nextToken']}
    return rows
```