# query cloudwatch logs for distinct values using boto3 in python

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a lambda function that writes metrics to `Cloudwatch`.  While, it writes metrics, It generates some logs in a log-group.

```
INFO:: username: simran+test@abc.com ClinicID: 7667 nodename: MacBook-Pro-2.local

INFO:: username: simran+test2@abc.com ClinicID: 7669 nodename: MacBook-Pro-3.local

INFO:: username: simran+test@abc.com ClinicID: 7668 nodename: MacBook-Pro-4.local

INFO:: username: simran+test3@abc.com ClinicID: 7667 nodename: MacBook-Pro-5.local

INFO:: username: simran+test3@abc.com ClinicID: 7667 nodename: MacBook-Pro-2.local
```

I need an efficient way to get **distinct values** of `nodename` for a given `ClinicId`. For example, I pass in `7667` for `ClinicId` and I expect

```
['MacBook-Pro-2.local', 'MacBook-Pro-5.local']
```

This is what I tried:

```
 query = "fields @timestamp, @message | parse @message \"username: * ClinicID: * nodename: *\" as username, ClinicID, nodename | filter ClinicID = "+ clinic_id

 start_query_response = client.start_query(
        logGroupName=log_group,
        startTime=int(time.mktime((Util.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=hours)).timetuple())),
        endTime=int(time.mktime(Util.utcnow().timetuple())),
        queryString=query,
    )
```

I considered iterating `start_query_response` in Python but I do not like that idea. Since it is logs for over `7 days` that I will be looking at, I need an efficient way instead of having to iterate each log from past `7 days` for the given `ClinicID`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pipe you expression to the `stat` command and count occurrences of each nodename.

Add this to the end of your query:

```
| stats count(*) by nodename
```

Result will be:

```
{
  'results': [
    [
      {
        'field': 'nodename',
        'value': 'MacBook-Pro-2.local\n'
      },
      {
        'field': 'count(*)',
        'value': '2'
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        'field': 'nodename',
        'value': 'MacBook-Pro-5.local\n'
      },
      {
        'field': 'count(*)',
        'value': '1'
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

See here for more details on various commands: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html